# cambiar fondo a vistas en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, css

Resulta que tengo en CSS un fondo:

```
body{
    background-image: url("../images/fondo_mix.png");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Lo utilizo en todas las vistas, excepto en dos las cuales tienen fondos distintos, y necesito cambiarlos, ustedes como sugieren el cambio? saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con ng-style

Esta directiva permite modificar el estilo CSS de un tag pero definiendo el estilo como un objeto del $scope. Dicho objeto tendrá propiedades cuyo nombre será el nombre del estilo CSS y el valor de la propiedad será el valor del estilo CSS.

Es decir que si creamos el siguiente objeto JavaScript en el $scope:

```js
$scope.estilo={
   'background-image': 'url("../images/xxxxx.png")'
}
```

y a un  tag HTML, le ponemos lo siguiente:

```html
<body ng-style="estilo"></body>
```

Comment: no funciona, entendí que al asignarle el ng-style al body del index, donde este el $scope (controller) aplicara el estilo, es así?

Comment: si en el controlador le agrego ese estilo y al agregarle en el body el ng-style con la referencia al estilo debería funcionar.

Comment: me alegra que te funcionara. Saludos desde Paraguay